# Strange bug from opencv rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I want to draw a box on image with different colors each boxes. So I write a simple code like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
thickness = 2

for i in range(len(x1)):
    start_point = (x1[i],y1[i])
    end_point = (x2[i],y2[i])
    color = list(np.random.randint(0,255,[3,]))
    cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)
```

And it raised an error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)`. Then I change `color = list(np.random.randint(0,255,[3,]))` to `color = [0,0,0]` and the result is normal. Therefore, I check a little:

```
color1 = list(np.random.randint(0,255,[3,]))
color2 = [0,0,0]
print(color1,color2)
print(type(color1), type(color2))
```

It was the same value and same type.

```
>> [111, 61, 27] [0, 0, 0]
>> <class 'list'> <class 'list'>
```

This problem really confused me, if you know why is it, please help me.

Comment: At which line did you get the error?

Comment: @Shreya the cv2.rectangle line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the `rectangle` function has problems with the np.int64 type. If you try `print(type(color1[0]), type(color2[0]))` you will find that they are of different types with one being `<class 'numpy.int64'>` and the other `<class 'int'>`. To use your random function, you will need to convert the integers to python integers, adding the following may help `color = [int(i) for i in color]`. This will draw the rectangle and not throw any errors

Comment: Okay, I didn't think about that situation, thanks for your help